# Why is nth-of-type acting like nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to alternate color for elements of a certain class and ignore any elements of different classes in between them. `nth-of-type` should provide this capability but in Firefox and Chrome, it acts incorrectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/rbe5oz52/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="section">Section</div>
    <div class="section">Section</div>
    <div class="ignoreMe">IgnoreMe</div>
    <div class="section">Section</div>
    <div class="section">Section</div>
</div>

.parent .section
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.parent .section:nth-of-type(2n+1)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

It should show the sections as red, yellow, red, yellow, but the `ignoreMe` element throws this off and causes two yellows in a row.

The definition says this should work the way I want:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

> This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if you want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag **no matter where it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear before it.**

How do i fix this?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `nth-of-class`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Vucko can I put the class in the selector?

Comment: How about using the `adjacent selector`? - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbe5oz52/1/)

Comment: @Vucko That doesn't work if there's more sections. But it's a good thought! http://jsfiddle.net/rbe5oz52/2/

Comment: @Vucko can you make your first comment an answer?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of questions, but it has an excellent signpost title. I updated my answer to one of the duplicates to address the title of this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 .parent .section
{
    background-color: red;
}

.parent .section:nth-of-type(2n+1)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shellyjindal/hL97tn2x/5/